# Create CASE WHEN labels based on DISTINCT values in a particular column

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have data of the following form:

| ID | Category | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 |
| 1 | B | 200 |
| 1 | B | 150 |
| 1 | C | 500 |
| 2 | B | 20 |
| 3 | A | 100 |
| 1 | B | 100 |

I wish to GROUP BY the column ID, find out the DISTINCT types of Category present for each ID group and create a new column where I can create the following classification labels for each grouped ID based on the unique or distinct categories present and also calculate the corresponding sum of amount for each grouped ID. So the output should be the follows:

| ID | Classification | Sum of Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ALL | 950 |
| 1 | B only | 20 |
| 1 | A and B only | 200 |

I tried the following SQL code but it doesn't work, most likely because DISTINCT() command within a CASE WHEN statement cannot consider multiple values.

My query:

```
SELECT
ID,
(CASE WHEN DISTINCT(CATEGORY) IN ("A") then "A Only" WHEN WHEN DISTINCT(CATEGORY) IN ("B") THEN "B only"..........)
SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM Table
GROUP BY 1,2
```

I have tried multiple ways of using the DISTINCT statement with CASE WHEN but none of them works.

Comment: What are your expected results here? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: My bad. I had posted a badly formatted and worded question. I have edited the question and posted again.

Comment: "Englishing" a result isn't really something for SQL Server, if I am honest. if you have 4 values would would you expect something like `'A, B, C and D only'`? You could, however, easily get a delimited list in SQL. There are literally 100's (if not 1,000's) of duplicates of how to do that on [so] already. What were wrong with those? Also, don't use ordinal positions in the `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY` clause; define the column/expression you want to use properly. If you want to reuse an expression often, you can use a CTE, or `VALUES` table expression to define and alias it for ease.

Comment: @Larnu 
1) Yes, if I had 4 values, I would have expected an output something like that.
2) I have used ordinal positions in the GROUP BY clause since I am running this on Hive QL.

Comment: If you're using Hive, why have you tagged [tag:sql-server]?

Comment: @Larnu Have corrected the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . How about this?

```
select id,
       (case when min(category) = max(category)
             then min(category) || ' only'
             when count(distinct category) = 3
             then 'All'
             when min(category) is NULL
             then 'None'
             else min(category) || ' and ' || max(category)
        end)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: I get the following error: "AnalysisException: GROUP BY expression must not contain aggregate functions: 10".
Also can you confirm that there shouldn't be a bracket after the DISTINCT command that you have used? Should it be COUNT(DISTINCT category) or COUNT(DISTINCT(category))?

Comment: @ShikhinMehrotra . . . You changed the database tag on the question.  Hive uses the standard `||` operator rather than `+`.  *Tag your questions correctly!*. And parentheses are not needed and not recommended when using `DISTINCT`.